# Batch file move browser or application to the left of screen

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, vbscript, move

I have the below code in the batch file and want to move the application or the browser which is opened using the below code on the left of the screen so that both the opened windows i.e application and browser should be placed side by side and not overlapped as such.

```
<!-- // batch / HTA hybrid script

@echo off

start saplogon.exe

rem // invoke HTA chimera for VBScript
mshta "%~f0"

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

// HTA chimera -->
<script language="VBscript">

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate2 "https://www.google.com"

IE.width = 700
IE.height = 600

IE.visible = true

close()

</script>
```

Comment: As I [mentioned before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31077715/1683264), you'll have to use [something a little more advanced](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16126938/1683264) than pure batch or Wscript for that sort of thing.