# Batch / bat file help - IE options and resizing

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to figure out a way to execute commands using a batch file to complete a particular action - the action is opening up a IE window for a specific link using extra features such as status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no + setting size of window.

This is the script that is run through browser, when it accomplishes the same thing I am trying to do. `window.open('/xx/xx/xx.htm','newWin','status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,height=640,width=640,center')`

Using something simple like this, allows me to open a window fine but does not allow for extra options as mentioned above, or resizing of window

```
start iexplore http://x.x.x.com/x/x
```

I have seen being able to use -k as a flag to force IE into full screen mode without any toolbars etc but that is not what I am looking for. I would like to be able to specifically define what I do and don't want included, through a batch file.

My only issue with window resizing is that I cannot use autohotkey or similar, if possible only through batch would be best but if other solutions with javascript are avail I would like to hear of those as well.

Comment: With pure batch there is no way, I think, unless `iexplore.exe` supports specific command line switches for all the things you want;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31077715/1683264 maybe?  In a cmd prompt, enter `powershell "new-object -COM InternetExplorer.Application | get-member"` to see the methods allowed by the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object.